# What is the initial value of an argument in a function within a function?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Using the code below:

```
 function makeAddFunction(amount) {
     function add(number) {
         return number + amount;
     }
     return add;
 }

 var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
 var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);
 console.log(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

The console prints out 9. I am assuming 'number' in the add function is zero but why is the value of 'number' initially 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "initially 0" about this.

You're first returning a function that adds 2 to a number, then making a function that adds 5 to a number.

thus, you've effectively written:

`console.log((2 + 1) + (5 + 1));`

and 3 + 6 is 9.

addTwo is essentially:

```
var addTwo = function (number) {
     return number + 2;
 }
```

add addFive is:

```
var addFive = function (number) {
     return number + 5;
 }
```

because you're using this as a [closure](http://web.archive.org/web/20080209105120/http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies).

Comment: Just added closures to my arsenal. this made alot of sense. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you call `makeAddFunction`, it takes the parameter you passed in for `amount` and then returns that inner function.

Thus when you pass in 2, it returns this:

```
 function add(number) {
     return number + 2;
 }
```

Then you are setting that code to the `addTwo` variable. So when you call `addTwo` with a parameter of 1, it returns 1+2 (3)